# How can I update a field in a MYSQL table with the result of a query over the same database table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL database with one table named students.
The table has three fields namely, regNumber, fullName, and email.
The email field is currently empty for all records in the table.
I am able to generate email addresses based on the regNumber and fullName columns.
Below is the SQL script for achieving that:

```
SELECT  
    REPLACE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullName, ' ', 1), ' ', -1), 1, 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullName, ' ', 3), ' ', -1),
    SUBSTRING(regNumber, 7, 4), "@ut.edu.ua"), '`', '') AS student_email 
FROM students;
```

However, I want to update the email field of every tupple with the result of executing the above script. How can I possibly achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update students
set email = REPLACE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullName, ' ', 1), ' ', -1), 1, 1),
            SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullName, ' ', 3), ' ', -1),
            SUBSTRING(regNumber, 7, 4), "@ut.edu.ua"), '`', '')
```